# Unity launcher for KDE

Tags: unity, launcher, kde

I'm a KDE user which is currently using Unity.
I really liked the Unity launcher, but really prefer the KDE desktop.

So, I was wondering whether there's a chance that a KDE plasmoid which implements the Unity launcher to be developed. Things like having launchers and running applications combined, and ideally supporting all other Unity features (like quick lists, counters, progress bars).

I think the same way Canonical developed a global menu plasmoid, having an Unity launcher plasmoid would be a great addition as well.

I know the Unity 2D launcher can be installed in KDE, but it is a total alien there, so I don't consider it as an alternative in it's current form...

Comment: i doudbt it, i recall a statement, that said that whatever the KDE team wanted to do with Kubuntu was up to them, and that the Kubuntu team wanted to keep vanilla KDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new task manager plasmoid, Icon Tasks has some nice features that including Unity API support.

http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/Icon+Tasks?content=144808

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look for Avant Window Manager alternatives for QT or use its GTK version with QTCurve or something. I remember that AWN has combined launchers and running applications, although not progress bars, counters or quick lists. However, it can replace a complete panel in lots of cases.